# To Register Cloud Firestore with Facebook Input

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-facebook-login

I can log in with Facebook, but I can not register Cloud Firestore. How do I get the resources to suggest? I can log in with Google, but here I have problems. I've shared the codes below. I'm not receiving an error. The information comes from Facebook but clicking on the button on the try catch process:

```
Future<Kullanici> facebookIleGiris() async {
 
  print("Login wiht facebook");
  FacebookLoginResult _result = await _facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
  switch(_result.status){
    case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    print("user logout");
    break;
    case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
      print("error");
      break;
    case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
      await _loginWithFacebook(_result);
    break;
  }
}
 
_loginWithFacebook(FacebookLoginResult _result) async {
  FacebookAccessToken accessToken = _result.accessToken;
  AuthCredential _credential =
  FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: accessToken.token);
  AuthResult result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(_credential);
  print('${result.user.uid}  ');
  print('${result.user.displayName} now login');
  print('${result.user.email}  ');
  print('${result.user.photoUrl}   ');
  print('${result.user.phoneNumber}');
  return _kullaniciOlustur(result.user);
```

ButtonClick

```
void _faceIleGiris() async {
  print("user clicked");
  var _yetkilendirmeServisi = Provider.of<YetkilendirmeServisi>(context, listen: false);
  print("user 2. step");
 
  try {
    Kullanici kullanici = await _yetkilendirmeServisi.facebookIleGiris();
    print("kullanici kontrole başladi ${kullanici.email}");
 
    if (kullanici != null) {
      print(" ${kullanici.email}");
 
      Kullanici fireStoreKullanici = await FirestoreServisi().kullaniciGetir(kullanici.id);
      if (fireStoreKullanici == null) {
        print("user created ${kullanici.email}");
 
        FirestoreServisi().kullaniciOlustur(
            id: kullanici.id,
            email: kullanici.email,
            kullaniciAdi: kullanici.userName,
            fotoUrl: kullanici.fotoUrl
        );
        print(" ${kullanici.email}");
        print("the end");
      }
    }
  }
      catch(ex){
    print(ex);
  }
```

User.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.d art';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore. dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth. dart';
class Kullanici{
  final String id;
  final String userName;
  final String email;
  final String fotoUrl;
 
  Kullanici({@required this.id, this.userName, this.email, this.fotoUrl});
 
  factory Kullanici.firebasedenUret(FirebaseUser user){
    return Kullanici(id:user.uid,
    userName: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
      fotoUrl: user.photoUrl
    );
 
 
  }
 
  factory Kullanici.dokumandanuret(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return Kullanici(
        id: doc.documentID,
        userName: doc['kullaniciAdi'],
        email: doc['email'],
      fotoUrl: doc['fotoUrl']
 
    );
  }
}
```

createUser method:

```
//Kullaniciolustur
class FirestoreServisi{
  final Firestore _firestore= Firestore.instance;
  Future<void> kullaniciOlustur({id,email,kullaniciAdi, fotoUrl=""}) async {
    await  _firestore.collection("kullanicilar").document(id).setData({
      "kullaniciAdi":kullaniciAdi,
        "email":email,
      "fotoUrl":fotoUrl,
      "dTarih":""
    });
    
  }
```

Comment: You want to set up [Facebook single sign-on and Firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) and the issue is that the federation between these two is not being created correctly as Firebase is not getting all information from the user. Is this what you are trying to achieve and what the issue is? 
Otherwise, please describe the goal and the issue.

Comment: I couldn't save the data to Firestore. But I have been right now.

Comment: Can you please share your solution so that community could use it as well?

Comment: I threw in response. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the FacebookIleGiris () method is logged in with Facebook, the function to be initiated to the initiated function and the error has been solved.

```
facebookIleGiris() async {
    print("facebook ile giriş başladi");
    FacebookLoginResult _result = await _facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
    switch(_result.status){
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
       var a= await  _loginWithFacebook(_result);
       return a;
      break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
      print("kullanici çıktı");
      break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print("error");
        break;
    }
  }
 _loginWithFacebook(FacebookLoginResult _result) async {
    FacebookAccessToken accessToken = _result.accessToken;
    AuthCredential _credential =
    FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: accessToken.token);
    AuthResult result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(_credential);
    print('${result.user.uid}  ');
    print('${result.user.displayName} şimdi giriş yaptı');
    print('${result.user.photoUrl}  ');
    print('${result.user.email}   ');
    print(result.runtimeType);
    return _kullaniciOlustur(result.user);
```